# jQuery - Remove prop if parent has class

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm building a form and I use jquery validate to check the fields.
I have 4 sub categories, when you click on one it obtains the class "choice" and a input text is appearing to specify the amount. I tried to make a condition that if the item had the class "choice", it adds 'required' to the input. But I cannot remove it if another item is selected. Here is my code :

```
jQuery('.offres_abo').click(function() {
  jQuery('.offres_abo').removeClass('choice');
  jQuery(this).addClass('choice');
  if (jQuery('.offres_abo').hasClass('choice')) {
    jQuery(".offres_abo.choice input").prop('required', true);
  } else {
    jQuery(".offres_abo.choice input").prop('required', false);
  }
});
```

---

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3 offres_abo choice">
  <button type="button" name="button">
   <span class="item_name"><p>Offre d&#8217;essai<br />
    3 COLIS/AN</p>
   </span>
   <span class="item_desc"><p>1 colis par mois (excepté juillet)</p></span>
   <span class="item_price">39 €/an</span>
   <span class="item_price_comp"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="nb_items">
   <span>Quantité x</span>
   <input id="offre_bronze" type="text" name="offre_bronze" required>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: need the html structure too

Comment: I believe this `jQuery('.offres_abo').hasClass('choice')` is returning a collection, not a single element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select items you need to modify before removing the class

```
jQuery('.offres_abo').click(function(){
    jQuery('.offres_abo.choice')
        .removeClass('choice')
        .find('input')
        .prop('required', false);

    jQuery(this)
        .addClass('choice')
        .find('input')
        .prop('required', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Yury Tarabanko answer, if you want to use `hasClass` for several items, you could use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

```
$('.offres_abo').each(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('choice')) {
    // code
  }
});
```